# Desabilitar Input se Determinado Button Radio Estiver Selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário de cadastro, que a pessoa seleciona se ela é Pessoa Física ou Jurídica, e aparecem os campos para preenchimento ao selecionar e tenho um script Jquery que faz a validação para que seja obrigatório a seleção e preenchimento destes campos após a seleção.

Se Pessoa Física, aparece CPF (obrigatório) e RG (obrigatório);

Se Pessoa Jurídica, aparece Razão Social (obrigatório), CNPJ (obrigatório) e I.E;

Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, mas devido a validação, eu preciso que ao escolher por exemplo `Pessoa Física` os campos da pessoa jurídica ficassem com o html `disabled="disabled"` ou alguma função que deixasse desabilitado o campo. Pois do jeito que se encontra, mesmo ele estando oculto o script de validação tenta validá-lo, sendo assim retornando erro.

## [Veja aqui o script em funcionamento](http://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/GjQKkd).

Obs: Para testar a validação é necessário clicar para preencher o campo `Email`.

HTML:

```
<div id="custom-field1" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="3" style="display: block;">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo de Pessoa</label><br><br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-3" value="3">Pessoa Física</label><br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-4" value="4">Pessoa Jurídica</label>
</div><br>


<div id="div-custom-field4" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="4" style="display: none;">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field4">Razão Social</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][4]" value="" placeholder="Razão Social" id="input-custom-field4" class="form-control">
    <label for="label-custom-field4" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label>
</div>

<div id="div-custom-field5" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="5" style="display: none;"><br>
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field5">CNPJ</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][5]" value="" placeholder="__.___.___/____-__" id="input-custom-field5" class="form-control cpf_cnpj" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="label-custom-field5" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label>
</div>

<div id="div-custom-field6" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="6" style="display: none;"><br>
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field6">I.E</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][6]" value="" placeholder="I.E" id="input-custom-field6" class="form-control">
    <label for="label-custom-field6" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label><br><br>
</div>


<div id="div-custom-field3" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="5" style="display: none;">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field3">CPF</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][3]" value="" placeholder="___.___.___-__" id="input-custom-field3" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="label-custom-field3" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label><br><br>
</div>


<div id="div-custom-field2" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="4" style="display: none;">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field2">RG</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="RG" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control cpf_cnpj">
    <label for="label-custom-field2" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label><br><br>
</div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-email">E-mail</label><br>
<input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail" id="input-email" class="form-control">
```

PARTE DO JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:radio[name^="custom_field[account][1]"]').on("change", function() {
    var chosen = this.checked && this.value == '3';
    $("#div-custom-field2, #div-custom-field3").toggle(chosen).find('input').attr('disabled', !chosen);

    $("#div-custom-field4, #div-custom-field5, #div-custom-field6").toggle(!chosen).find('input').attr('disabled', chosen);
});

$('[id^="input-custom-field"]:disabled').closest('.form-group.custom-field').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa verificar que opção esta marcada no radio e só aplicar a validação apropriada.

Existem alguns elementos com o mesmo id (`id="campo-obrigatorio"`) o parâmetro ID deve ser sempre único, apesar de as vezes funcionar, efeitos indesejáveis costumam acontecer, quando precisar selecionar vários elementos em uma seleção prefira usar uma `class`.

Segue abaixo algumas modificações comentadas:

```js
// função ready esta obsoleto
$(function() {
  // definir variavel global com o radiogroup
  var $radio = $('input:radio[name^="custom_field[account][1]"]');

  $radio.on("change", function() {
    var chosen = this.checked && this.value == '3';
    $("#div-custom-field2, #div-custom-field3").toggle(chosen).find('input').attr('disabled', !chosen);

    $("#div-custom-field4, #div-custom-field5, #div-custom-field6").toggle(!chosen).find('input').attr('disabled', chosen);
  });

  $('[id^="input-custom-field"]:disabled').closest('.form-group.custom-field').hide();

  $("#input-payment-custom-field3").addClass('cpf_cnpj');
  $("#input-payment-custom-field5").addClass('cpf_cnpj');

  $("#input-email").focusin(function() {

    if (!$radio.is(':checked')) {
      alert("Escolha o tipo de pessoa");
      $radio.focus();
    }

    // checar se o radio selecionado é o CPF e aplicar a devida validação
    if ($radio.filter(':checked').val() == '3') {
      if (($('#input-custom-field2').val().length < 3) && ($('#input-custom-field3').val().length < 3)) {
        $('label[for="label-custom-field2"], label[for="label-custom-field3"]').addClass('c-obrigatorio text-danger');
        $("#input-custom-field2, #input-custom-field3").addClass('input-erro');
        $('label[for="label-custom-field4"], label[for="label-custom-field5"], label[for="label-custom-field6"]').addClass('e-obrigatorio');
        $('#input-custom-field3').focus();
      } else if ($('#input-custom-field3').val().length < 3) {
        $('label[for="label-custom-field3"]').addClass('c-obrigatorio text-danger');
        $("#input-custom-field3").addClass('input-erro');
        $('label[for="label-custom-field2"], label[for="label-custom-field4"], label[for="label-custom-field5"], label[for="label-custom-field6"]').addClass('e-obrigatorio');
        $('#input-custom-field3').focus();
      } else if ($('#input-custom-field2').val().length < 3) {
        $('label[for="label-custom-field2"]').addClass('c-obrigatorio text-danger');
        $("#input-custom-field2").addClass('input-erro');
        $('label[for="label-custom-field3"], label[for="label-custom-field4"], label[for="label-custom-field5"], label[for="label-custom-field6"]').addClass('e-obrigatorio');
        $('#input-custom-field2').focus();
      }
    }

    // checar se o radio selecionado é o CNPJ e aplicar a devida validação
    if ($radio.filter(':checked').val() == '4') {
      if (($('#input-custom-field4').val().length < 3) && ($('#input-custom-field5').val().length < 3)) {
        $('label[for="label-custom-field4"], label[for="label-custom-field5"]').addClass('c-obrigatorio text-danger');
        $("#input-custom-field4, #input-custom-field5").addClass('input-erro');
        $('#input-custom-field4').focus();
      } else if ($('#input-custom-field4').val().length < 3) {
        $('label[for="label-custom-field4"]').addClass('c-obrigatorio text-danger');
        $("#input-custom-field2").addClass('input-erro');
        $('label[for="label-custom-field2"], label[for="label-custom-field3"], label[for="label-custom-field5"], label[for="label-custom-field6"]').addClass('e-obrigatorio');
        $('#input-custom-field4').focus();
      } else if ($('#input-custom-field5').val().length < 3) {
        $('label[for="label-custom-field5"]').addClass('c-obrigatorio text-danger');
        $("#input-custom-field5").addClass('input-erro');
        $('label[for="label-custom-field2"], label[for="label-custom-field3"], label[for="label-custom-field4"], label[for="label-custom-field6"]').addClass('e-obrigatorio');
        $('#input-custom-field5').focus();
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.c-obrigatorio {
  display: block !important;
}
.e-obrigatorio {
  display: none !important;
}
.input-erro {
  border-color: #a94442;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-field1" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="3" style="display: block;">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo de Pessoa</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-3" value="3">Pessoa Física</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-4" value="4">Pessoa Jurídica</label>
</div>
<br>


<div id="div-custom-field4" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="4" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field4">Razão Social</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][4]" value="" placeholder="Razão Social" id="input-custom-field4" class="form-control">
  <label for="label-custom-field4" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label>
</div>

<div id="div-custom-field5" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="5" style="display: none;">
  <br>
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field5">CNPJ</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][5]" value="" placeholder="__.___.___/____-__" id="input-custom-field5" class="form-control cpf_cnpj" autocomplete="off">
  <label for="label-custom-field5" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label>
</div>

<div id="div-custom-field6" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="6" style="display: none;">
  <br>
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field6">I.E</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][6]" value="" placeholder="I.E" id="input-custom-field6" class="form-control">
  <label for="label-custom-field6" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>


<div id="div-custom-field3" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="5" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field3">CPF</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][3]" value="" placeholder="___.___.___-__" id="input-custom-field3" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
  <label for="label-custom-field3" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>


<div id="div-custom-field2" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="4" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-custom-field2">RG</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="RG" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control cpf_cnpj">
  <label for="label-custom-field2" id="campo-obrigatorio" style="display:none">Campo obrigatório</label>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-email">E-mail</label>
<br>
<input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail" id="input-email" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Eu quebrei a cabeça aqui pensando em uma solução e você trouxe ela de forma bem simples, apenas criando uma verificação de antes de validar! Obrigado pelo ajuda!